# Qubes OS Installer shows Debian11

Tags: system-installation, qubes

I am trying to install Qubes OS via an iso image on a USB stick. Version R4.0.4.
I checked the release signing key and the hash value of the iso image.
But the graphical installer keeps showing me a Debian11 logo, and says Debian11 everywhere.
The official Qubes installation tutorial has photos in it indicating that it should say Qubes R.4.0.4 instead: https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/installation-guide/

While this is not strictly a technical problem, I wonder why this happens, and if it's safe to proceed with the installation.

Edit @KnutLarsen: That's very weird. Mine looked just like this: https://www.debugpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Debian-11-Installer.jpg
And also after installation, it looks like a plain Debian11. Could it be that creating the installation stick with "Startup Disk Creator" is a problem?

Comment: Qubes-R4.1.0-x86_64 shows the "Fedora anaconda installer" https://www.qubes-os.org/attachment/doc/installation-summary-not-ready.png → With a Q backsplash. ( I'm running the Qubes installer just now.)

Answer (score 1):

Now it worked:
I created the installation stick with `dd` rather than Startup Disk Creator, and I chose a bigger USB stick. The former one had only 4GB while the iso image was bigger than 5GB, but Startup Disk Creator didn't inform me about it and exited with a 'success' message nevertheless.